# how to paginate firestore data in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I want to make pages like 1,2,3 from firestore documents.
But don't know what to do!

So I need pagination functionality like this :

- if the total number of documents in the collection is 26 then it should be divided into 3 pages, as 0-9, 11-19, 20- 26 documents
- when I click on **page no 2** it should fetch 11-19 documents.

**So here I also need to find how many documents are there so I can make pages (like 1,2,3) from that**

**What I tried**

- I tried firebase's official doc [firebase query cursor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)
- I also tried the [paginate_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/paginate_firestore) plugin (but It is not compatible with my requirement)
- If I am on the 1st page and go to the 3rd page directly, it should fetch 21-26 records (as per example given above)

**What I want**

- for example: when we search in google, at bottom of the page there are pages as (1,2,3 more) so I want similar to this

Comment: Hi, Can you please elaborate your question and tell us what you have tried and what is the output that you are receiving. Provide minimum code, you can read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: Check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Answer (score 0):

May be help you [paginate_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/paginate_firestore) package.

Comment: this plugin is not about what I expect, I want to create page numbers at the bottom of the page as (1, 2, 3, next) and click on page number, it should fetch documents according to that!

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61572813/10187218. 
I have no idea if that doesn't work either