# How paging work with realtime firestore query?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am confused how to make pagination with realtime firestore query:

```
const subscriber = firestore()
        .collection('notifications')
        .doc(authenticatedUser.uid)
        .collection('notificationItems')
        .orderBy('createdDate', 'desc')
        .limit(5)
        .onSnapshot(response => {
          setNotifications(response.docs); // Settings all to app state
```

With this I receive realtime updates from firestore but how to append new data and continue to listen.
If I call this again then I get new subscriber.
Can somebody hint me just how to append new items and continue listening changes?
Just to be clear I am keeping reference to the last item from response and then use `startAfter()` to get next item I just don't know how to do the same with `onSnapshot`

Comment: There seem to be quite some relevant hits when I [search for firestore realtime pagination](https://www.google.com/search?q=firestore+realtime+pagination), so that'd probably be a good page to start. Sorry for the non-answer, but pagination on a data set that changes in realtime is notoriously hard (believe me: we tried) as a general use-case.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that edit: you should be able to pass a query with a `startAfter` condition to `onSnapshot` too. Doesn't that work for you? Any error?

Comment: This is for non constantly changing data liek notifications and chat messages those data never change but I need to listen for new but I can't load chat with 1000 message documents :)

Comment: But if I call this function again then on each page I get new subscriber and I really need just one. Am I correct?

Comment: Uhm... it depends.... :(
If your data set is append-only, one options is to create a new query every time you need a new page, with a larger `limit`. If you have disk caching enabled/or attach the new `onSnapshot` before cancelling the previous one, this will only read the documents in the new page from the server.

Comment: This is how looks advanced paginated query. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70773801/6310260, but it is not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If your data set is append-only, one option is to create a new query every time you need a new page, with a larger `limit`. You wouldn't actually need a `startAfter` clause when you do that.

So for the first page, you'd start with `limit(5)`. Then for loading the second page, you use `limit(10)`, and so on.

If you have disk caching enabled/or attach the new `onSnapshot` before cancelling the previous one, this will only read the documents in the new page from the server.