How does Firestore calculate read count for same queries with different limits?
I am trying to paginate the "messages" collection query using limit.
_chatReference
    .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
    .limit(limit)
    .snapshots()
    .doOnListen(() => print('Chat stream started with limit $limit'))
    .doOnCancel(() => print('Chat stream cancelled for limit $limit'))

As soon as the user reaches the scroll end I am increasing the limit. But when I increase the limit do I get charged for the last limit + new limit or just the new limit?
Ex- If I call the query with the limit of 20 and then increase it to 40 what is the total read count? Is it 40 or 60?
What if the query stream with a limit of 20 cancelled before listening to the stream with a limit of 40?

If I understand correctly this you pay by document reads so if the new query reads 40 documents instead of 20 than you will be charged 20+40.

But in that 40 reads 20 is same anyway.

I know but I don't think it matters. I am not sure that's why I didn't post an answer but reading the documentation makes me think that Firestore will read 40 documents and charge you for that.

This answer from Frank made me think so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73338011/how-paging-work-with-realtime-firestore-query

I've found this package to work great for such scenarios, if you're using firestore:  https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_firestore

@Lostsaka That won't work  for realtime data

I'm pretty sure it does, since I'm already using it. When an existing document updates, the change is dynamically fetched and updated, as a snapshot.

@Lostsaka Not about update. What happens when new doc get's appended?

It gets appended to the existing list: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes:~:text=FlutterFire%20provides%20support%20for%20dealing%20with%20realtime%20changes%20to%20collections%20and%20documents.%20A%20new%20event%20is%20provided%20on%20the%20initial%20request%2C%20and%20any%20subsequent%20changes%20to%20collection/document%20whenever%20a%20change%20occurs%20(modification%2C%20deleted%20or%20added).

@Lostsaka it will in a normal query but not in a paginated query

@Praveena Did you try it?

If you say that when you first time launch the app, you're getting 20 documents, then you'll be charged with 20 document reads. If you increase the limit from 20 to 40, this means that you'll be charged with 20 more document reads. So there will be a total of 40 reads. You won't be charged again with the initial 20 reads, because those 20 documents are already in the cache.
Be aware that this mechanism works, only if you're attaching a real-time listener. If you intent to use a get() call, you'll be charged for document reads each time you perform a query.

Thank You Alex. For that to happen I should  start listening to query with limit 40 before canceling the query with limit 20 right?

It's not about canceling the query, but detaching a listener when it is no longer needed. So if the first listener is no longer needed, because the second one provides exactly the documents you need, then there is no need to keep it active. Also, remember that you'll not pay for documents that are already in cache, but for the documents that are changed on the Firebase servers.

This is how I implemented the pagination now - I am maintaining the limit as a state variable and incrementing it whenever the user reaches the end of the scrollview. Also using useeffect on limit state and canceling the previous subscription and firing the new one with the new limit.

Firestore Calculation for Paginated Queries
The Answer
Let me explain how Firestore manages read counts in your pagination scenario.
Concerning Active Streams
_chatReference.orderBy('createdAt', descending: true).limit(limit).snapshots();


Changing the barrier from 20 to 40 results in only being charged for 40 reads, not 60. Firestore is clever enough to identify that this is an update to an existing query. The server only sends the required additional 20 documents.
Regarding Canceled Streams
If you stop a stream with limit 20 before beginning a new one with limit 40:

Initial inquiry: Initial inquiry: 20 exams.
The second question had 40 reads
Total: 60 readings.

This is because:
Cancelling the stream disrupts the connection. The new stream must fetch all documents fresh. Each individual stream counts as a new query.
Best Practices
To maximize read counts:
// Modify the existing stream:
StreamController<int> limitController = StreamController();

_chatReference
    .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
    .limit(limitController.stream.value)
    .snapshots();

// Update the limit
limitController.add(newLimit);

Instead of adding new streams, use:
A single stream has a changeable limit. Update the limit as necessary. Keep the stream alive until it is no longer needed.
