# firestore query error for subcollections: rest.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to count the number of branches of all restaurants. "Branch" is a sub collection of "Restaurants". When I try to do this query, there is an error:

> rest.collection is not a function

Here's my code. How can I fix it?

```js
async function getBranch(){ 
  const size = 0;
  const restRef = await firebase.firestore().collection('Restaurants').get();
  restRef.forEach((rest) => {
    const branchRef = rest.collection('Branch').get();
    size = size + branchRef.size();
  })
  return size;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to provide id of restaurants to get the subcollection. So better make reference for `Restaurants` and get all `branches`

```
async function getBranch(){ 
  const size = 0;
  const restRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Restaurants');
  const restRes = await restRef.get();
  restRef.forEach((rest) => {
    const branchRef = await restRef.doc(rest.id).collection('Branch').get();
    size = size + branchRef.size();
  })
  return size;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ashish, you should not use async/await in a forEach loop, see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=forEach+async

Comment: In the loop the callback function is called but it does not wait for it to be completed before going to the next entry of the array. Have a look at https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404. To solve it, use the "technique" I indicated in my answer (`Promise.all()`) or other ones detailed in some of the answers I pointed to above.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follow, by using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (untested).

```
async function getBranch(){ 
  let size = 0;
  const restQS = await firebase.firestore().collection('Restaurants').get();

  const promises = [];
  restQS.forEach((rest) => {
     promises.push(rest.collection('Branch').get());
  });

  const querySnapshotsArray = await Promise.all(promises);

  querySnapshotsArray.forEach(qs => {
     size += qs.size;   // <= Note that size is a property of the QuerySnapshot, not  a method
  })
  
  return size;
}
```

---

Another approach would be to query all your branch doc with a [Collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), if the only collections named `Branch` are subcollection of Restaurants.

```
const branchQS = await firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('Branch').get();
return branchQS.size;
```

---

#### HOWEVER,

you should note that this implies that **you read ALL the documents of ALL the (sub)collections** each time you want to get the number of `branch` documents and, therefore, it has a cost.

So, if your collections have a lot of documents, a more affordable approach would be to maintain a set of distributed counters that hold the number of documents. Each time you add/remove a document, you increase/decrease the counters.

See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) in the doc for more details, as well as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61250956/3371862).