# how can I get the length from this query snapshot on firestore firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting videos from firebase firestore by using this query:

`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('videos').where('uid',isEqualTo: widget.uid).get();`

I am getting the videos of particular user id but how can I get the length of videos that how many videos has been posted/stored by this particular current user 'uid'. I want to know the numbers of videos that user holds. So basically I need this to hide the container where I display videos, if there is no video by this user id.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, you should use the [`size`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/size.html) property, as follows for example.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('videos')
.where('uid',isEqualTo: widget.uid)
.get()
.then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    Print(querySnapshot.size);
});
```

**HOWEVER**, you should note that this implies that you read all the documents corresponding to the query each time you want to get the number of videos and, therefore, it has a cost. If your collection is and stays small, using the `size` method can be a good approach.

But if the collection is going to contain a lot of docs and you often need to get the number of docs, better use another approach, like maintaining one or more counters. See these answers for examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61250956/3371862), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553314/how-to-get-a-count-of-number-of-documents-in-a-collection-with-cloud-firestore) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554091/cloud-firestore-collection-count/49407570#49407570).

Comment: @GAGANSINGH Hello, did you have the time to look at the answer?